# Solution to a partial differential equation example

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was wondering on how to deal with the following PDE. I can see it is on the form of a heat equation, but I just want to know how to solve this concrete example by "hand", i.e. without computer programs. The equation is given below.

$$u_x=2u_{yy}, \hskip 0.5cm u(2,y)=y^2.$$

The solution in Maple 2020 is
$$u=y^2+4x-8.$$

Any suggestion, books, methods are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Separation of variables ? Take the PDE and turn it into 2ODEs

Comment: Ohh yes, good suggestion, let me use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can suppose that $$u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$$so, you can see that $$u_{x}=YX' \quad u_{yy}=XY''$$Then, $$u_{x}=2u_{yy} \iff YX'=2XY'' \iff \frac{X'}{2X}=\frac{Y''}{Y}=-\lambda$$ and you can the use method of separation of variables that you know in ODE.

Comment: I ended with the solution $u(x,y)={\frac {AB\sin \left(  \sqrt{\lambda}y \right) }{ \left( {{\rm e}^{
\lambda\,x}} \right) ^{2}}}+{\frac {AC\cos \left(  \sqrt{\lambda}y
 \right) }{ \left( {{\rm e}^{\lambda\,x}} \right) ^{2}}}$. Checking, this solves my PDE, but the next problem is that I cannot find $u(2,y)=y^2$. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried substituting the initial conditions to ur function u ?

Comment: Yeah and it won’t work for me, I cannot figure out on how I can reach the beautiful solution by the solution I already have.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\on{u}\pars{x,y} \equiv \on{a}\pars{x} + \on{b}\pars{y}
\\[5mm]
&\on{a}'\pars{x} = 2\on{b}''\pars{y} = \alpha = \mbox{constant}
\\[5mm] &\
\on{a}\pars{x} = \alpha x + \beta,\qquad
\on{b}\pars{y} = {1 \over 4}\,\alpha y^{2} + cy + d
\\ &\
y^{2} = \on{u}\pars{2,y} = \pars{2\alpha + \beta} +
\pars{{1 \over 4}\,\alpha y^{2} + cy + d}
\\ &\
{1 \over 4}\alpha = 1,\quad
\bbx{c = 0},\quad
2\alpha + \beta + d = 0
\\ &\ \implies \bbx{\alpha = 4},\quad
\bbx{\beta + d = -8}
\\ &\
\bbx{\on{u}\pars{x,y} = 4x + y^{2} - 8} \\ &
\end{align}